# How to set List child element with for each If it is empty initially?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I  have Ilist to get all Offer from repository using entity framework core. Also I have service model OfferResponseModel which includes
OfferRequestModel as reference. I used mapster to bind entity model to service model. However it only set first child. Now I want to bind it manually. I created "offers" with the size of "Offer". When I try to use foreach loop, I cannot set "offers" child element.Because it has no elements. So, I can I solve this.

var offer = await _unitOfWork.Offers.GetAllOffer();

```
if (offer == null)
    throw ServiceExceptions.OfferNotFound;

var results = new List<OfferResponseModel>(offer.Count);
results.ForEach(c => { c.Offer = new OfferRequestModel(); });

int i = 0;

foreach(var result in results)
{
    result.Offer.User = Offer[i].User.Adapt<UserResponseModel>();
    result.Offer.Responsible = Offer[i].Responsible.Adapt<EmployeeResponseModel>();
    result.CreatedDate = Offer[i].CreatedDate;
    result.ModifiedBy = Guid.Parse(Offer[i].UpdatedBy);
    result.Active = Offer[i].Status;
    result.Offer = Offer[i].Offer;
    result.Offer.User.Company = Offer[i].Company.Adapt<CompanyModel>();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created "offers" with the size of "Offer".

No, you created it with that *capacity*. It's still an empty list. It's not clear to me why you're trying to take this approach at all - it looks like you want one `OfferResponseModel` for each entry in `offer`, directly from that - which you can do with a single LINQ query. (I'm assuming that `offer` and `Offer` are equivalent here.)

```
var results = Offer.Select(o => new OfferResponseModel
    {
        Offer = new OfferRequestModel
        { 
            User = o.User.Adapt<UserResponseModel>(),
            Responsible = o.Responsible.Adapt<EmployeeResponseModel>()
        },
        CreatedDate = o.CreatedDate,
        ModifiedBy = Guid.Parse(o.UpdatedBy),
        Active = o.Status
    }).ToList();
```

That doesn't set the `Offer.User.Company` in each entry, but your original code is odd as it sets the `User` and `Responsible` properties in the original `Offer` property, and then replaces the `Offer` with `Offer[i].Offer`. (Aside from anything else, I'd suggest trying to use the term "offer" less frequently - just changing the plural to "offers" would help.)

I suspect that with the approach I've outlined above, you'll be able to work out what you want and express it more clearly anyway. You definitely don't need to take the "multiple loops" approach of your original code.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have left out is the type of the `offer` variable that is referenced in the code. But I am thinking you need to do something along these lines:

```
if (offer == null)
    throw ServiceExceptions.OfferNotFound;

var results = offer.Select(o => new OfferResponseModel 
{
    Offer = new OfferRequestModel 
    {
        User = o.User.Adapt<UserResponseModel>(),
        Responsible = o.Responsible.Adapt<EmployeeResponseModel>(),
        ...
    }
}).ToList();
```

`Select` basically loops through any items in `offer` and "converts" them to other objects, in this case `OfferResponseModel`. So inside select you simply new up an OfferResponseModel and directly sets all the properties you need to set.

You need `using System.Linq;` for Select to be available.

Comment: @Daisy beat me to it by 30 seconds, looks like pretty much the identical answer :)